# Doubled gap between button and card - Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm learning to create pages by Materialize CSS.
Actually I've problem with gap between down edge of submit button and edge of card. (look screen)
In my opionion that gap is doubled than it should.

Please help!
Thank you to everyone who interested! <3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <title>Login page</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-box row valign-wrapper">
            <div class="col s12 m4 offset-m4">
                <div class="card">
                    <form class="card-content">
                        <div class="row login-title">
                            <span class="card-title">Training Login Form</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-field col s12 m6">
                                <label for="username">Login</label>
                                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Type your login">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-field col s12 m6">
                                <label for="username">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" id="username" placeholder="Type your password">
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="rememberPass">
                                <span>Remember password?</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12" type="submit" name="action">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>             
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materialize uses `margin-bottom: 20px` on all `.row` - remove it for the last `.row` and you'll remove the excess spacing.

```
.card-content .row:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/oNjEBVy).

I recommend getting to grips with using the inspector in chrome - highlight the element causing you problems, and see visually what margin and padding are being applied, update directly in the console, and then you can write the appropriate style rule in your css.

[image: inspector]

Comment: Yeeeah! Good to know! Thank you a lot <3

Comment: Cool, if it's the correct answer, please mark it so others can find the answer as well - and feel free to upvote :)